# Closing routes on event - Angular2

Tags: routes, angular2-routing

Lets say I have a default, and a named router. 
My routes are this.

```
{ path: 'path', component: MyComponent },
{ path: 'named-path', component: SecondComponent, outlet: 'second' }
```

If I want to close a named route, I can do that with this

```
this.router.navigate(['', { outlets: { second: null } }]);
```

How am I able to close the route that does not have the named outlet(In this case the first route)?

Comment: what are you expecting with `closing route`, isn't navigating to another route same as closing route?

Comment: I have 2 different routes displayed on the same page.

Comment: that you already mentioned, that you have a main route and a named route, but what do you mean by `close the route that does not have the named outlet`?

Comment: Closing the main route.

Comment: isn't navigating to another route same as closing route?

Comment: As I said already, I have 2 different routes displayed on the same page, something opens something in one, something in the other route. I want to be able to click on a button, close route(doesnt matter which one right now).